# Как обработать на кнопке UI Button, вместо OnClick(), сделать действие на стрелочки направо или влево

Tags: unity3d

Это мне нужно что бы поменять текст для громкости, если игрок нажимает направо в кнопке то текст менялся на соответствующий текст с громкостью, или налево, не могу понять как это сделать. Или что хотя бы надо изучить, просто совсем не понятно, как и с чем это связано, вроде бы связано с Event System, но что как это оформить воовсе не ясно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем так и не получил ответа и не нашел его в интернете, пришлось писать костыль.
Код который позволяет узнать выбрана ли сейчас кнопка, и нажимается ли влево или вправо.

```
public class ButtonSound : MonoBehaviour
{
     private void Update()
     {
       if (gameObject == EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject)
       {
          if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) 
          {
              print("ВЛЕВО");
          }

          if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.RightArrow)) 
          {
              print("Вправо");
          }
       }
     }

}
```

Comment: `GetKeyDown`... `EventSystem` тут не нужен.